# 2x2 confusion matrix in three-class classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, confusion-matrix, multiclass-classification

I am doing classification on a dataset with three classes (Labels Low, Medium, High).

I run the following code to get my confusion matrix:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

And I get the following output for `cm`:

```
array([[18, 10],
       [ 7, 61]], dtype=int64)
```

What does this output mean? I read the following link but didn't understood
[Confusion Matrix and Class Statistics](https://towardsdatascience.com/confusion-matrix-and-class-statistics-68b79f4f510b)

Comment: how about [scikit docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#confusion-matrix)?

Comment: [tag:spyder] has nothing at all to do with this, it's only an IDE, it's not going to affect how your code runs. The relevant tags are [tag:scikit-learn], [tag:classification], [tag:multiclass-classification]

Comment: If you have three different classes in `y`, then confusion matrix should have been 3x3. Could you check if all labels exist in `y_test` and `y_pred`?

Comment: You say you have three classes, but it looks like your classifier only did two-class. Post us the code you used for training your classifier. In particular make sure you're passing the label column in correctly.

Comment: You haven't posted the code for your classifier, so we can't solve why it only trained to two classes not three. SO rules require you to [Minimal, Complete Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

This is the explanation of what you get.

**For any NxN confusion matrix the following holds:**

**Actual**: is the true labels

[image]

---

**For a 2x2 case (simpler explanation):**

[image]

---

Read also this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#confusion-matrix

Answer (score -1):

Let us take a closer look at the results:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = np.array([[18, 10],
                           [ 7, 61]]).ravel()
```

Which means:

```
tn (True Negative) = 18
fp (False Positive) = 10
fn (False Negative) = 7 
tp (True Positive) = 61
```

In other words,

- 18 class-0 samples classified (correctly) as class-0
- 10 class-0 samples classified (incorrectly) as class-1
- 7 class-1 samples classified (incorrectly) as class-0
- 61 class-1 samples classified (correctly) as class-1

You could also directly use

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred).ravel()
```